# Batch strip portions of a filename in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch, rename

In windows 7, i have a ton of files that have unnecessary prefixes and postfixes to their filenames. How can i, using some form of batch tool, remove them? `ren` didn't work on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) It's free, does not require installation and does just about everything possible where renaming files is concerned.

Comment: This has to at least be a competitor for most crammed UI I've seen but it did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/downloads.php?project=ReNamer) is a powerful utility to batch rename files and folders in Windows. There is also a [pretty complete guide](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-batch-rename-multiple-files-and-folders-in-windows-instantly/) for it.

With ReNamer you can create rules that are applied (after a preview) to all selected files.